# Compare hours (string to hour and actual hour)

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to compare the actual hour and minutes with a string like this "18:00". I get the actual hour and minutes like this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
```

I have an string like this "18:00" (TAG_HORA) and I am trying to compare 2 dates like this:

```
dateCompareOne = parseDate(c.getString(TAG_HORA));
if ((dateCompareOne.after(date))){//...
```

I don´t get a result, somebody can help me? Thanks

Comment: you should better extract hours and minutes from the date then compare it with hours and minutes extracted from TAG_HORA. It is cleaner than building a fake date.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? thanks

Comment: after(..) returns a boolean. After invoking "after" what happens? If you don't get a result then you are getting an exception

Comment: Doesn´t do well the comparation because it returns hours before actual hour, I want only get hours after the actual hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this could help:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class test
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    date1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date1.getTime().getHours() );
    date1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date1.getTime().getMinutes() );
    date1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    String reference = "18:00";
    String[] parts = reference.split(":");
    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    date2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
    date2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    date2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (date1.before(date2)) {
        System.out.println(date1.getTime()+" vs "+date2.getTime());
        System.out.println("Not yet at the limit");
    }

  }
}
```

EDIT: the output is:

```
Sat Jul 01 16:05:00 GMT+01:00 2017 vs Sat Jul 01 18:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017
Not yet at the limit
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract hours and minutes from `TAG_HORA` with `String.split()` and `Integer.valueOf()`. Then, it is easy to compare the times.

```
Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
int nowHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int nowMin = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


String hora = "18:00";
String[] parts = hora.split(":");

int horaHour = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
int horaMinute = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);

if(60 * nowHour + nowMin > 60 * horaHour + horaMinute) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don'y mind about the second and the milliseconds you can do as the flowing:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
now.getTimeInMillis();
```

parse the value passes with key TAGֹ_HORA.
and than compare using <>= sings